# How to group the same "type elements" from a nested list of tuples?

Tags: python, data-structures, nested-lists

Given a list of nested lists:

```
pairs = [['A', 'berries'], ['A', 'bananas'], ['B', 'apples'], ['C', 'oranges'], ['C', 'apricots'], ['C', 'tomatoes']]
```

How to nest the elements of the `l` by grouping them into "list types" such as (*):

```
[
  [['A', 'berries'], ['A', 'bananas']], 
  [['B', 'apples']], 
  [['C', 'oranges'], ['C', 'apricots'], ['C', 'tomatoes']]
]
```

So far I tried the following:

```
def get_type(e):
    return str(e[0])


for e in pairs:
    l = []
    if e[0] == get_type(e):
        l.append(e)
    else:
        pass

print(l)
```

However, the above is not grouping the elements of the same type:

```
[['A', 'berries']]
[['A', 'bananas']]
[['B', 'apples']]
[['C', 'oranges']]
[['C', 'apricots']]
[['C', 'tomatoes']]
```

Instead it is only appending each element into a new list insted of creating groups as (*).

Comment: "the above is not grouping the elements of the same type" - What is it doing instead? Which output does it produce? Did it raise any errors?

Comment: @The_spider is only adding each element into a new list, instead of grouping them. Any idea about how to group those elements into lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `groupby` method from the *itertools* module:

```py
from itertools import groupby

grouped_list = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(l, lambda x: x[0])]

>>> grouped_list
# [[['A', 'berries'], ['A', 'bannanas']], [['B', 'apples']], [['C', 'oranges'], ['C', 'apricots'], ['C', 'tomatoes']]]
```

Comment: Oh, did not know that there was a group by function in itertools!